# Is using SUDO in the terminal of the Mac safe?

Tags: terminal, permissions, java, sudo

I've recently begun programming in Java using VS Code. Recently, I purchased a used 2019 MacBook Touch Bar, and I'm still getting used to using the terminal to troubleshoot issues.

Regrettably, I used the SUDO command to grant permission to clear the Java cache (`java -Xshare:dump`), and now I'm concerned that I may have made a mistake or left my computer vulnerable to attacks. I'm even hesitant to use the `java -Xshare:dump` command now. Could you please clarify if I've given more permission than necessary or done something wrong?

Initially, the issue arose with the error message "A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again" when running a Java code. This is a recent problem as I was able to use Java successfully before.

Comment: “Regrettably, I used the SUDO command to grant permission to clear the Java cache (`java -Xshare:dump`), and now I'm concerned that I may have made a mistake or left my computer vulnerable to attacks. I'm even hesitant to use the `java -Xshare:dump` command now.” Why? Do you have any problems? Why are you concerned? You did nothing wrong. It should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sudo` doesn't grant any permissions. It uses permissions already granted - usually to yourself as administrator.
It's only 'dangerous' because it lets you do things ordinarily locked from inexperienced users. On a Mac, it won't let you damage the system, only your user area, if handled injudiciously.

I don't know what you thought you were trying to do with Java, but `java -Xshare:dump` is for creating CDS Archives - see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/java.html

Answer (score 0):

On my system when I try to run the command (without sudo): `java -Xshare:dump`

It tries to write to the location:
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/classes.jsa`

Because I haven't used `sudo` the write fails and the the command aborts.

I doubt you have "left your computer vulnerable to attacks" since you are effectively creating a cache of class files for quick application startup. However depending exactly what arguments you gave to the dump command, you may have created a cache with classes which could potentially become stale (hence you may end up with odd errors when running Java apps). In the worst possible case you may need to uninstall and re-install your JDK to make sure it's clean.

However there is another lesson here - don't run commands with `sudo` unless you have some idea of what they are going to do.

Answer (score 0):

sudo gives you superuser permissions for a single command, requiring a password. Then it remembers the password for some time, so you can enter multiple sudo commands easier.

There are two risks: The first risk is that you do something you shouldn’t, which wouldn’t have been allowed without sudo, and mess up your computer. The second risk is that you walk away from your computer while it still remembers your password, and I sit down at the keyboard and mess up your computer. On the other hand, if I can access your computer, I can erase everything in your user directory, which for a typical Mac user is about as bad as messing up the system.

Good news: After a short time, when your Mac has forgotten your sudo password, there is nothing that I can do to cause damage that I couldn’t have done before you used sudo.